# How to create a custom Horizontal SeekBar

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I am working on an android app and trying to create a custom horizontal SeekBar.Its working but showing vertical SeekBar.I am sharing my code .Let me know how to change the orientation of the SeekBar. Please help if possible.

**Java File for custom Seeking bar ::**

```
package android.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

 public class HSeekBar extends SeekBar {

    public HSeekBar(Context context) {
       super(context);
   }

   public HSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)    {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   }

   public HSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
   }

  protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
  }

   @Override
   protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int  heightMeasureSpec) {
      super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
     setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
  }

  protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    c.rotate(90);
    c.translate(getHeight(),0);

    super.onDraw(c);
   }

  @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    }

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            int i=0;
            i=getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight());
            setProgress(i);
            Log.i("Progress",getProgress()+"");
            onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
       }
    return true;
    }

  }
```

**Xml file**

```
 <android.widget.HSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/hbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dip"
            android:max="200"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/style"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_image" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `SeekBar` is horizontal by default. The rotation you're doing in `onDraw()`, and the swapping of measured dimensions in `onMeasure()` is what's causing yours to appear vertical.

Answer (score 1):

```
          <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/value"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:max="100" />
```

Just using "android:rotation="90"" or android:rotationX or android:rotationY
to get rotation for seekbar